# image url variable from db in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I want show image using url from the db.

Like this

```
<img class="card-img" src="{{travel.city}}" alt="Card image">
```

{{travel.city}} is a variable from v-for loop. this v-foor loop is working.

Comment: Is the `img`  element rendering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use v-bind directive:

```
<img v-bind:src="travel.city">
```

Or short:

```
<img :src="travel.city">
```

Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the syntax for [attribute binding](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes) instead:

```
<img class="card-img" :src="travel.city" alt="Card image">
```

Vue doesn't support interpolation of mustache-style templates in attributes (like Angular or other frameworks do).